# Does scons support subversion checkout?

Tags: svn, scons

From some sites it seems Scons support subversion checkout:

```
env = Environment()
env.SourceCode('.', env.Subversion('XXX'))
env.Program('hello.c')
```

http://www.scons.org/doc/0.92/HTML/scons-user/x1625.html

But from the man page/user guide of the latest stable version(2.0.0) there is no subversion.
It's not mentioned in the change log. So I am wondering what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of things, [SourceCode has been deprecated in 2.0](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.scons.devel/9065). There has been very little discussion about the deprecation recently. The release note for 2.0 says:

> - The SourceCode() function and its associated factory functions
>     have started their deprecation cycle and can have a warning enabled.

And the [ChangeLog](http://www.scons.org/CHANGES.txt) also mentions it briefly:

> - Start deprecation cycle for SourceCode() and related factories

Digging in the mailing list reveals that there was [a poll in October 2008](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.scons.devel/6775). The reason for the deprecation seems to have been that `SourceCode()` added a great deal of complexity to the codebase, was not used much in the wild, did not support anything other than legacy RCS and SCCS very well, had buggy Subversion support, and was generally not worth keeping around.

Most replies to the poll said "I don't use this feature", with the occasional "yes it is buggy" or "why would you mix the source code control and the build system anyway?".