# Can scons be used to automatically update your working copy?

Tags: scons

Bit of confusion. It looks like SCons can be used to automatically get things from the repository if they're not present in your working copy, but maybe not? The documentation is conflicting at best. Does anyone know if this is possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278832) regarding Subversion checkouts. The answer is that SCons *used to* support this, but the developers deprecated it in more recent versions.

An alternative approach is to use a network mounted drive together with SCons' [Repository](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/c3906.html#AEN3910) feature. This is more like Make's VPATH feature than a source code repository like CVS or Subversion though.